# DynamodDB - Pay per hour/minute (STORAGE COST)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

Imagine I need a temporary DynamoDB table (created from the latest BACKUP) to run a performance test and as soon as the test is finished I would DROP/REMOVE that table (and its underlying storage).

Let's say that test required 1TB of storage and ran for 4 hours. How much would I be charged FOR THE STORAGE?

Would I have to pay for the whole month (720 hours) or for the fraction (4/720) of the time I actually used the STORAGE?

Cheers